# I want to create several clickable play icons/buttons that play music from a specific URL

Tags: javascript, elementor

I'm working inside Elementor and I want to create multiple clickable play icons that play audio from my media library (on various parts of a tuition style website page). Bit of a JS newbie, but so far I have:

```js
<script>
  let audioButton = document.querySelector('.audio-button1'); 
  audioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio");
    if (audio1.paused) {
      audio1.play();
    } else {
      audio1.pause();
      // audio.currentTime = 0
    }
  });
</script>
<audio id="audio" src="MY URL"></audio>
```

So far this all works when you click the play icon (with the `audio-button1` class). I'd like to be able to add more play icons that link to other short audio clips, like Example 1, Example 2 etc., but I'm scratching my head as to how to do this... Any help greatly appreciated!

I've tried a few things by tweaking the script for another icon/button but I'm super slow at this and can't figure it out... I assume JS is the best way to do this, but perhaps there's a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I gave each play button a data attribute that references the audio's ID. I did this so you could put the button and audio in different places instead of relying on the audio being after the button.

Then I loop through the buttons and add an event listener to each to handle the playing.

In playing I first loop through the audio objects and pause any that are playing.

After that I use the button's data-audio in a querySelector to reference the audio element that needs to play and play it. I don't need an if statement here as the loop through audio sources would have paused it anyway.

```
<button data-audio="#audio1" class="btnPlay">Play</button>
<audio id="audio1" src="MY URL"></audio> 

<button data-audio="#audio2" class="btnPlay">Play</button>
<audio id="audio2" src="MY URL"></audio> 

<button data-audio="#audio3" class="btnPlay">Play</button>
<audio id="audio3" src="MY URL"></audio> 

<button data-audio="#audio4" class="btnPlay">Play</button>
<audio id="audio4" src="MY URL"></audio> 

<button data-audio="#audio5" class="btnPlay">Play</button>
<audio id="audio5" src="MY URL"></audio>

const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btnPlay");

const playAudio = (e) => {
  const audioSources = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
  
  audioSources.forEach((a) => {
    if(!a.paused)a.pause();
  });

  const audio = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.audio)
  audio.play();
}

btns.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click",playAudio))
```

Comment: imvain2 - that works really nicely! I'm just wondering if there's a way to pause the currently playing audio when a user clicks on the same button. At the moment it pauses for a few milliseconds than starts again from where it left off